# Clicklistener / Touchlistener on elements inside NestedScrollview do intercept scroll

Tags: android, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener, android-cardview, nestedscrollview

My structure looks like this:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
 <AppBarLayout>
  <CollpasingToolbarLayout>
   <ImageView />
   <Toolbar />
  </CollpasingToolbarLayout>
 </AppBarLayout>
 <NestedScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>
   <CardView>
     <LinearLayout />
   <CardView>
    ....
  </LinearLayout>
 </NestedScrollView>
 <TextView />
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've got a onClick/onTouchListener on the cardview elements. The onTouch/onClick events work. But the scrollview gets intercepted if I want to start the scroll on one of the card elements that has a onClickListener on it it just doesn't scroll at all.

On a very similar but older structure it worked, but now I tried everything but I still can't figure out what I'm missing.

Does anybody have an idea ?

Thanks a lot
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the Android Support Library. See here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182549

Comment: Thanks! - I have seen the post.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. This was fixed for me with the latest support library release (23.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Make sure your `gradle` dependencies include:

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'

You can read [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2015/10/android-support-library-231.html) for further insight regarding the new support library update!